# How to add a table to a new page in an ItextSharp PdfStamper

Tags: itext

I'm using ItextSharp to populate a Pdf template with data. The template is a single page form with a number of input fields. I can create a PdfStamper and populate the fields with no problem, however, I want to add a second page to the stamper and then add a dynamically created PdfPtable to that page. I can add a page using stamper.InsertPage(2,reader.GetpageSize()) but I can not work out how to add the table to the page.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Get your new page's `PdfContentByte`, then use `PdfPTable.WriteSelectedRows()`.  There are 4 different overrides providing you with various options.

`WriteSelectedRows` just takes row [& column] numbers to draw, an X/Y location, and a `PdfContentByte` or array of same.  This means it won't do any page breaking or width validation or what have you.  It'll just draw what you ask it to draw, where you ask it to draw it.  You have to do all the layout yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm sure your way is probably more correct but I managed to hack a solution by creating the two pages as separate files and then concatenating using PdfSmartCopy. Thanks anyway!